# TestNG/Surefire: How to generate an XML report after each test?

Tags: java, testing, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

We have a large number of complex integration tests that run for several hours. 
How do I receive TestNG XML reports while the tests are running, not after the run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a TestNG listener which extends `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter` and override its `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter#onFinish` wherein you can build the logic to push the results of a `<test>` tag after its run to a data source of your own. You can also try making it more real-time by building an implementation of the listener interface `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener` and within `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener#afterInvocation` check if a `method` is a test method and if yes, start recording the results to a data source of your choice.